# Oracle:Compare multiple rows in same table on date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to get results based on following conditions.
My table have following columns id, updateFlag, updateTime.
Criteria, if multiple **updateDates** are same get id one with updateFlag ='Y' else get the latest **updateTime** **id**.

Here is my SQL Script;

updateFlag possible values 'Y','N',null

```
create table customer(id varchar2(20),updateFlag char(1),updateTime DATE);
insert into customer(id,updateFlag,updateTime) values(1,'N',to_date('16-JAN-20 04.54.37','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS'));
insert into customer(id,updateFlag,updateTime) values(2,'N',to_date('16-JAN-20 04.54.37','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS'));
insert into customer(id,updateFlag,updateTime) values(3,'Y',to_date('16-JAN-20 04.54.37','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS'));
commit;
```

when i use following query it works fine since one of the flag is 'Y';

```
select * from customer where id in(1,2,3) and  updateFlag='Y' order by updateTime;
```

but when i insert following script with mix of nulls and 'N'  for updateFlags  i expect to get
'N'.

```
insert into customer(id,updateFlag,updateTime) values(1,'N',to_date('16-JAN-20 04.54.37','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS'));
insert into customer(id,updateFlag,updateTime) values(2,'N',to_date('16-JAN-20 04.54.37','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS'));
insert into customer(id,updateFlag,updateTime) values(3,null,to_date('16-JAN-20 04.54.37','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS'));
```

and one more condition if recent updateTime not equal to other rows get the recent id.

[image]

Appreciated the help.

Sorry for confusion rephrasing the question here.

1. Get the id based on most recent updatedTime.
2. If there are two or more recent updatedTime with same value ,get the id which have the updatedFlag='Y'
3. If there are two or more recent updatedTime with same value ,but none of have flag 'Y' get the value with 'N'.

Comment: Please show us the result that you would expect for the second dataset. Also, since it seems like there is an additional condition (* if recent updateTime not equal to other rows get the recent id*), you would probably need to show us sample data and expected result for that use case too.

Comment: @Rocky4Ever, some feedback would be nice. People did try to help you... Did any of the answers below helped ? If not, why not ? Show the output you want to get from the data you presented. Are the presented data correct...?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.I did update my questions.The following answers helped partially.But not fully.May be I will rephrase my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `analytical function` as following:

```
Select * from 
(select c.*, 
       row_number() over (order by updatetime desc, updateflag desc nulls last) as rn
from customer c
where id in (1, 2, 3))
Where rn = 1
```

Cheers!!

Comment: This returns multiple columns ,where as I am expecting just one column with most recent updatedTime.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, but query fails if the recent updatedFlag is 'N' and old id have 'Y'.As we only want to compare if there updatedTime is duplicate else ,we just get the most recent updated record.And I updated my question, please check.

Comment: Ok. That was misunderstood. Just changed the columns in order by clause. Check now!!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want one row.  This orders them so the one you want is first:

```
select *
from customer c
where id in (1, 2, 3) 
order by (case when updateFlag = 'Y' then 1 else 2 end),  -- put those first
         updateTime;
```

Then use either `fetch first 1 row only` in Oracle 12C+ or a subquery with `rownum = 1` in the outer query  to get just one row.

Comment: This works fine when there is updatedFlag='Y'.If there is no 'Y' i want the record with 'N' if all nulls in updatedFlag ,i want to retrieve first id.And if the updatedTime is unique then would like retrieve that one only.

Comment: @Rocky4Ever  . .  Your right.  The condition on `updatedflag` should not have been in the `where`.

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to understand what you want without the example data you expect to get from your query.
Bu if you want to get only one row from the first set of data you have given us and one more from the other set of data you have given us then this would be the query you need.

First I need to say that I have assumed that you have made a mistake with data you have given us. updateDates in second set of that should be different than the first one? Maybe I am wrong...

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8b7c976eb16ef5ed6c722154c0a96b73)

```
select * from customer 
where (updateTime, id) in (
select updateTime, max(case when updateFlag = 'Y' then id 
            else (select max(id) from customer c where c.id = c1.id)
       end)
from customer c1
group by updateTime);
```

Or if you want min ID then:

```
select * from customer 
where (updateTime, id) in (
select updateTime, min(case when updateFlag = 'Y' then id 
            else (select min(id) from customer c where c.id = c1.id)
       end)
from customer c1
group by updateTime);
```

Comment: If all Flags are 'N' then this query fails.

Comment: HI @Rocky4Ever, thank you for your feedback. I do not know what do you mean. Hee is example that it returns value if all flags are N: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=732b35c085ade7e5b9f3bc768cb313fb

Comment: Also, @Rocky4Ever, I have seen you find this answer helpul and one answer is correct. Please note that you can give an vote up to every answer that is helpful and you can also accept one answer that is correct.